# Rscript running on R

Tags: r, rscript

I am a new user of R and I am stuck. I want to execute a Rscript that will allow me to compute some indices using the [CLIMPACT](https://github.com/ARCCSS-extremes/climpact2) package for many stations once. Here is what the manual says to do:

[image: SS of Instructions]

I don't really know how to run my script in R to get results. Please help me Thanks

Comment: Where do these instructions come from? Can you provide sample `r` or `linux` code that you have tried so far? Currently, it is hard to diagnose your problem. Please [consider reading this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to improve your question.

Comment: What have you tried to do? The Rscript command just runs a specified R Script. The manual you linked to provides pretty explicit instructions for what arguments to pass it. If that's confusing you, start with a basic tutorial on using the command line. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your posting the question and welcome to Stack Overflow.

1. As I understand you could not run RScript at Linux.
2. To solve it please follow the instructions [Using RScript at Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1131925/using-rscript-in-linux-server) & execute:.

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/home/mydirectory/R-3.1.2/bin/"
   ```
3. I think your question is more fit to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and it is better be migrated. As [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is about programming and SuperUser is about software and hardware itself (installation problems included). Posting this kind of question on Super User will increase a probability of answer significantly.